# HTML - insert user-created HTML into a HTML page: escaping and discarding format

Tags: html

I have an HTML page which needs to display some HTML generated by the user on the Administration area (like a blog, for instance). The problem is that the user sometimes needs to copy-paste tables and other "garbage" content from Word/Excel to the WYSIWYG editor (that has the proper "paste from Word" function). This causes the resulting HTML code to be very dirty.

It wouldn't be a problem unless some of these pages are shown totally wrong: other divs AFTER user's HTML code are not in their supposed position, floats are not respected... etc...

I tried putting a div:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

without success. I even tried with iFrames, but iFrames accept only external webpages (if applicable...).

The question is: is there any tag or method to put a part of an HTML code inside a webpage discarding all formatting AFTER this code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you simply want to end all divs. HTML is a very simple code, with very simple options. Your  example doesn't work because HTML isn't that advances. You can either start a function <...> or end a function .

Ideally what you want is a piece of code that puts their work in a separate frame entirely, so as soon as the page passes their code, it goes back to the correct formatting.

Or, you could be really sloppy and put one hundred 's in, just in case.